# Retaining line breaks when using HtmlAgilityPack's InnerText to extract emails

Tags: c#, regex, html-agility-pack

I am using HTMLAgiltyPack to extract email addresses that are embedded within the queries sent to us. The HTML section in question is in the following form:

```
<div class="queryBody">
 <span>
   ****Query here****
   MAY contain paragraphs and lists tags.
 </span>
</div>
```

This is my code:

```
string query = queryHtml.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
               @"//div[@class='queryBody']
               /span")[0].InnerText;
string pattern = @"([\w.]+)@([\w.]+)\.([a-z]+)";
Match match = Regex.Match(par, pattern);
string email = "";
if (match.Success)
{
    email = match.Value;
}
```

A problem arises when the HTML within the `<span>` contains paragraphs and lists. In this case, `query` will return one large string with all the line breaks from the `<p>` and `<li>` omitted.

Example:

```
<div class="queryBody">
  <span>
     <p>I am unable to log into my account</p>
     <p>Please help me sort out this problem</p>
     <p>My email is: rebecca.h@gmail.com</p>
     <p>cell: 021901493</p>
  </span>
</div>
```

`query` will return:

```
I am unable to log into my accountPlease help me sort out this problemMy email is: rebecca.h@gmail.comcell: 021901493
```

This makes it extremely difficult to use my regex pattern to extract the email address. Is there any way I can retain the line breaks while using HtmlAgilityPack to traverse the HTML nodes? Anything else I could do to extract the email addresses successfully?

Comment: I cannot repro. I get all line breaks there and the result is `rebecca.h@gmail.com`. If there are no linebreaks in the original HTML, then I can repro.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one email to extract, you may use

```
var query = queryHtml.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
           @"//div[@class='queryBody']
           /span");
var pattern = @"\S+@\S+\.\S+";
var email = "";
if (query != null)
{
    var emailNode = query.Descendants().Where(m => Regex.IsMatch(m.InnerText, pattern)).FirstOrDefault();
    if (emailNode != null)
    {
        email = Regex.Match(emailNode.InnerText, pattern).Value;
    }
}
```

The point is to find a descendant node that matches the email pattern (note I am using a more generic pattern for it, that matches 1+ non-whitespaces, `@`, 1+ non-whitespaces, `.` and again 1+ non-whitespaces), and then extract that match.

You may adjust the code for multiple emails easily by collecting all the nodes matching the pattern and then using `Regex.Matches` to get all the pattern matches.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex works with the raw html, so I would just use InnerHtml instead of InnerText. The code would just be.

```
string query = queryHtml.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
               @"//div[@class='queryBody']
               /span")[0].InnerHtml;
string pattern = @"([\w.]+)@([\w.]+)\.([a-z]+)";
Match match = Regex.Match(par, pattern);
string email = "";
if (match.Success)
{
    email = match.Value;
}
```

This will get the address correctly since '<' is not in [a-z]. Then if you do some reason need the InnerText I would just make that a separate variable.